# How to connect with database and return values using Async/await task in Web Api controller c#

Tags: c#, mysql, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, task

Hello i am trying to connect with database and return values from a web api controller.I want to do it all the way asynchronous with new task to have better performance if it is possible.here is an example of what i have done.Am i doing it the correct way?Am i using correct the using statements?is the await correct in Open,Close connection and sda.FillAsync ?Thanks!

```
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
 {
   return await Task.Run(() => GetAllCustomers());
 }

    private async Task <HttpResponseMessage> GetAllCustomers()
    {
        DataTable Customers= new DataTable();

        using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(""))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
        {
            try
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    await con.OpenAsync();
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    await sda.FillAsync(Customers);
                }
            }

            catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                await con.CloseAsync();
            }
        }
        return ControllerContext.Request
       .CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { Customers });
    }
```

Comment: Better suited on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: `public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()` AFAIK, it is recommend to call that Method `GetAsync` then.

Comment: I have a feeling that calling Task.Run explicitly is not needed in Get()

Comment: `catch (MySqlException ex)
            {
                ex.Message.ToString();` - this is completely useless. Log it at least. But better return an Error Response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for code review.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
return await Task.Run(() => GetAllCustomers());
```

with

```
return await GetAllCustomers();
```

You don't need to run the service task explicitly (the controller method is already marked as `async`).

Rename `GetAllCustomers` to `GetAllCustomersAsync` (best-practice naming convention)

I prefer to code WebApis this way:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get() 
{
    try 
    {
         var result = await GetAllCustomersAsync();
         return Ok(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) 
    {
        return InternalServerError(ex);
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:
An update to show how your database-operation can be simplified:

```
private async Task<Customers> GetAllCustomersAsync()
{
   var customers = new DataTable();
   using (var con = new MySqlConnection(""))
   using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", con))
   {
       await con.OpenAsync();
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
       var sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
       await sda.FillAsync(customers);
   }
   return customers;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! do you know if the await in Open,Close connection and sda.FillAsync is correct ?

Comment: I looks right (haven't tested). But I would remove the try-catch-finally block and the if-statement inside the try block. When you create a new connection it will start in a closed state. It shouldn't be necessary to close the connection. The connection is created inside a using-block, and will be disposed automatically (dispose = automatic close)